# can we make two launcher activities and launch one based on some condition?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

my launcher activity is loginActivity and i want that when the user selects a college and opens the app for the second time he should be moved to another activity TestYip (and not login activity). that is the launcher activty should change once the user has logged in. for this i made a fuction getCollege in Select_Collage activity which is called from the loginActivity .
but its not working.. the code is given :

1. Select_Collage

   ```
               package notes.test.firebase;

       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.HashMap;

       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.content.SharedPreferences;
       import android.os.Build;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.text.Editable;
       import android.text.TextWatcher;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.Window;
       import android.view.WindowManager;
       import android.widget.AdapterView;
       import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
       import android.widget.EditText;
       import android.widget.ListView;
       import android.widget.TextView;


       public class Select_Collage extends AppCompatActivity {

           // List view
           public ListView lv;
           public TextView tv;
           public String str;


           // Listview Adapter
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

           // Search EditText
           EditText inputSearch;

          final String products[] = {"Jaypee university Guna", "Delhi university", "Graphics era", "UPES",
                   "Amity university", "Saradha university",
                   "ITM gwalior", "RKDF university", "Indraprast university", "IIT delhi"};


           // ArrayList for Listview
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.collage);
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                   Window window = getWindow();
                   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                   window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                   window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
               }
               // Listview Data
              /* final String products[] = {"Jaypee university Guna", "Delhi university", "Graphics era", "UPES",
                       "Amity university", "Saradha university",
                       "ITM gwalior", "RKDF university", "Indraprast university", "IIT delhi"};

       */
               lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


               inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

               // Adding items to listview
               adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.college_selection_text_view, R.id.product_name, products);
               lv.setAdapter(adapter);

               lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                           long arg3){

                       tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.product_name);

                       str = tv.getText().toString().trim();

                       if (str.equals(products[0]))

                       {
                           Intent int0 = new Intent(Select_Collage.this, TestYip.class);
                           startActivity(int0);
                       }

                       else if(str.equals(products[1])) {
                           Intent int1 = new Intent(Select_Collage.this, MainListDisplay.class);
                           startActivity(int1);

                       }
                   }
               });
               /**
                * Enabling Search Filter
                * */
               inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                       // When user changed the Text
                       Select_Collage.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                 int arg3) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }


               });
                   }

           public void getCollege () {
               SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
               if (str.equals(products[0]))
               {
                   editor.putInt("key", 1);
                   editor.apply();
                   //Intent int0 = new Intent(getAppl,TestYip.class);
                   //Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TestYip.class);
                   //startActivity(int0);
               } else {
                   editor.putInt("key", 0);
                   editor.apply();
               }
           }
       }
   ```
2. LoginActivity

   ```
   package notes.test.firebase;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.text.TextUtils;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ProgressBar;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

   public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
       private FirebaseAuth auth;
       private ProgressBar progressBar;
       private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           //Get Firebase auth instance
           auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

           if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null ) {
               Select_Collage s = new Select_Collage();
               //s.getCollege();
               //startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
               s.getCollege();
               SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
               int i = preferences.getInt("key",0);
               ///startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
               if (i==1)
               {
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TestYip.class));
               }
               else
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));


           }

           // set the view now
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

           Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
           inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
           progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
           btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
           btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
           btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

           //Get Firebase auth instance
           auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

           btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
               }
           });

           btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
               }
           });

           btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                   final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       return;
                   }

                   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       return;
                   }

                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   //authenticate user
                   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                           .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                   // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                   // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                   // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                       // there was an error
                                       if (password.length() < 6) {
                                           inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                       } else {
                                           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       }
                                   } else {
                                       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                       startActivity(intent);
                                       finish();
                                   }
                               }
                           });
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. Android Manifest

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="notes.test.firebase">

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

       <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
           <activity
               android:name=".LoginActivity"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
           <activity
               android:name=".MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">




           </activity>
           <activity
               android:name=".SignupActivity"
               android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
           <activity
               android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity"
               android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
           <activity
               android:name=".TestYip"
               android:label="@string/title_test"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
           <activity android:name=".Computer_Notes" />
           <activity
               android:name=".MainListDisplay"
               android:label="@string/Select_Subject"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchResulltsActivity" />
           </activity>
           <activity
               android:name=".Select_Collage"
               android:label="@string/Select_Collage"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchResulltsActivity" />
           </activity>

           <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

           <activity android:name=".SearchResulltsActivity"
                     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
               <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                   android:value=".MainActivity"/>
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
               </intent-filter>
               <meta-data
                   android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
           </activity>
       </application>

   </manifest>
   ```

please tell how i can move from one activity to another based on a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend the best way around. Whenever you are stuck on such things, Splash screen will help you.

Let me explain how:-

Just make splash screen as Launcher activity. If you don't want that to display it for much longer, just have the handler run for 1-2 seconds. Now look at the code below.

> SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.apply();

        email = pref.getString("login", null);

        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

        if (email != null) {

            //It means User is already Logged in so I will take the user to Select_College Screen

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Select_College.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        } else {

            //It means User is not Logged in so I will take the user to Login Screen

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        }

    }
}
```

> Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_login);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);

        Login();

    }

    private void login() {

        //If login is successfull, before moving to next activity, store something in sharedpreference with name login. It can be email or just a string as "true"

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putString("login", email);
                        editor.apply();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(DoctorLogin.this, Select_Collage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

    }
}
```

> Select_Collage.java

```
public class Select_Collage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_message);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);

        //Somewhere on Signout button click, delete the login sharedpreference
        signOut();

    }

    private void signOut() {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.remove("login");
        editor.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Select_Collage.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

So that's how you can solve this problem. Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use LoginActivity as your launcher activity. In your LoginActivity, save some flag value to `SharedPreferences` to indicate the user has logged in, and then in the onCreate of your other Activity(Set this one to launcher), check for this value, if its not present, then go to LoginActivity.

Comment: how do we set `SharedPreferences` ? could you suggest an example? thankyou :)

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); editor.putString("login", email); editor.apply();

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a boolean or int in shared preference. 
Set the int or boolean in Select_collage
Get its value in LoginAcitivity  , and check condition the way you did it.

I guess the problem with your code is when you check condition in LoginAcitivity , the value in Select_collage activity is not set as it is not created.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a splashcreen activity.. in that activity u need to check the condition (`oncreate` function)
for which activity should be launch to the next..